# Multiprocessing thousands of files with external command

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, threadpool

I want to launch an external command from Python for about 8000 files. Every file is processed independently from the others. The only constraint is to continue execution once all files have been processed. I have 4 physical cores, each one with 2 logical cores (`multiprocessing.cpu_count()` returns 8). My idea was to use a pool of four parallel independent processes that are to be run on 4 of the 8 cores. This way my machine should be usable in the meantime.

Here's what I've been doing:

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import os
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def process_files(input_dir, output_dir, option):
    pool = ThreadPool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()/2)
    for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):  # about 8000 files
        f_in = os.path.join(input_dir, filename)
        f_out = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
        cmd = ['molconvert', option, f_in, '-o', f_out]
        pool.apply_async(subprocess.Popen, (cmd,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


def main():
    process_files('dir1', 'dir2', 'mol:H')
    do_some_stuff('dir2')
    process_files('dir2', 'dir3', 'mol:a')
    do_more_stuff('dir3')
```

A sequential treatment takes 120s for a batch of 100 files. The multiprocessing version outlined above (function `process_files`) takes only 20s for the batch. However, when I run `process_files` on the whole set of 8000 files, my PC hangs and does not un-freeze after one hour.

My questions are:

1) I thought `ThreadPool` is supposed to initialize a pool of processes (of `multiprocessing.cpu_count()/2` processes here, to be exact). However my computer hanging up on 8000 files but not on 100 suggests that maybe the size of the pool is not taken into account. Either that, or I'm doing something wrong. Could you explain?

2) Is this the right way to launch independent processes under Python when each of them must launch an external command, and in such a way that all the resources are not taken up by the processing?

Comment: I compared the solutions proposed by @larsks (`ThreadPool` with `apply_async` and subprocess `call`s) and @Roland Smith (manual pool management using `Popen` objects). My benchmark shows that the `ThreadPool` solution is faster in practice. Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your basic problem is the use of `subprocess.Popen`.  That method does **not** wait for a command to complete before returning.  Since the function returns immediately (even though the command is still running), the function is finished as far as your ThreadPool is concerned and it can spawn another...which means that you end up spawning 8000 or so processes.

You would probably have better luck using `subprocess.check_call`:

```
Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete.  If
the exit code was zero then return, otherwise raise
CalledProcessError.  The CalledProcessError object will have the
return code in the returncode attribute.
```

So:

```
def process_files(input_dir, output_dir, option):
    pool = ThreadPool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()/2)
    for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):  # about 8000 files
        f_in = os.path.join(input_dir, filename)
        f_out = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
        cmd = ['molconvert', option, f_in, '-o', f_out]
        pool.apply_async(subprocess.check_call, (cmd,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If you really don't care about the exit code, then you may want `subprocess.call`, which will not raise an exception in the event of a non-zero exit code from the process.

Comment: Thank you for this very clear and straight-to-the-facts explanation. Indeed `subprocess.Popen` must be what's causing the spawning of so many processes. I hadn't used `subprocess.call` thinking that Python would wait for the process to complete instead of filling the pool with useful workers. But that's why the pool is there for in the first place. (Sorry, rep too low, cannot upvote.)

Comment: You can still mark this as the "accepted" answer by clicking on the checkmark  to the left of this answer.

Comment: Yes yes, I know. The trouble is I'm having a difficult time making up my mind in deciding between the two very helpful answers (I'm currently testing the outcomes according to the two proposed solutions). :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3, I would consider using the `map` method of `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Alternatively, you can manage a list of subprocesses yourself.

The following example defines a function to start `ffmpeg` to convert a video file to Theora/Vorbis format. It returns a Popen object for each started subprocess.

```
def startencoder(iname, oname, offs=None):
    args = ['ffmpeg']
    if offs is not None and offs > 0:
        args += ['-ss', str(offs)]
    args += ['-i', iname, '-c:v', 'libtheora', '-q:v', '6', '-c:a',
            'libvorbis', '-q:a', '3', '-sn', oname]
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as bb:
        p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=bb, stderr=bb)
    return p
```

In the main program, a list of `Popen` objects representing running subprocesses is maintained like this.

```
outbase = tempname()
ogvlist = []
procs = []
maxprocs = cpu_count()
for n, ifile in enumerate(argv):
    # Wait while the list of processes is full.
    while len(procs) == maxprocs:
        manageprocs(procs)
    # Add a new process
    ogvname = outbase + '-{:03d}.ogv'.format(n + 1)
    procs.append(startencoder(ifile, ogvname, offset))
    ogvlist.append(ogvname)
# All jobs have been submitted, wail for them to finish.
while len(procs) > 0:
    manageprocs(procs)
```

So a new process is only started when there are less running subprocesses than cores. Code that is used multiple times is separated into the `manageprocs` function.

```
def manageprocs(proclist):
    for pr in proclist:
        if pr.poll() is not None:
            proclist.remove(pr)
    sleep(0.5)
```

The call to `sleep` is used to prevent the program from spinning in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` (still using Python 2.7 here). Thank you for this nice example of manual pool management. I had tried to do something similar (thinking I should't do `remove` on a list while iterating it) but something must have gone wrong. I will be testing this solution soon. (Sorry, rep too low, cannot upvote.)

Comment: I compared the two methods (your answer and @larsks'). I like this solution very much, but it would seem that manually managing the pool induces an overhead, probably due to the calls to `sleep` (I made the process manager sleep for 0.2 s as it seemed more appropriate). On a batch test 1/10th the size of my real input, manual pool management is 8% slower than `ThreadPool` on `cpu_count()-1` cores and 27% slower than `ThreadPool` on `cpu_count()/2` cores.

Comment: You'd have to do some real profiling to see where the difference comes from. There are a lot of factors that influence things. For example, it is not a given that `cpu_count()` is the *optimal* amount of subprocesses. You should probably try anything in a range from `cpu_count()/2` to `cpu_count()*2`. Furthermore, you should probably tune the amount of `sleep` depending on the time `molconvert` usually takes. But since I've completely switched to Python 3, I just tend to use a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` for stuff like this these days.